# Python rock, paper, scissors

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

Im trying to learn python and started with this, I keep getting a syntax error when i try to run it.  the cursor jumps to the end of the close " at def start section.  Im not sure where the syntax error is coming from as i speech mark all the print

```
#! python3

# J Presents: Rock, paper, Scissors: The Video Game

import random
import time

rock = 1
paper = 2
scissors = 3

names = { rock: "Rock", paper: "Paper", scissors: "Scissors" }
rules = {rock: scissors, paper: rock, scissors: paper}

Player_score = 0
computer_score = 0

def start ():
    print "Let's play a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors."
    while game ():
        pass
    scores()

def game ():
    player = move ()
    computer = random.randint(1, 3)
    result(player, computer)
    return play_again()

def move():
    while True:
        print
        player = raw_input("Rock = 1\nPaper = 2\nScissors = 3\nMake a Move: ")
        try:
            player = int(player)
            if player in (1,2,3):
                return player
            except ValueError:
                pass
            Print "Oops! I didn't understand that. Please enter 1, 2 or 3."

def result (player, computer):
    print "1..."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "2..."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "3!"
    time.sleep (0.5)
    print "Computer threw {0}!".format(names[computer])
    global player_score, computer_score
    if player == computer:
        print "Tie Game."
    else:
        if rules[player} == computer:
        print "Your victory has been assured."
        player_score +=1
    else:
        print "The computer laughs as you realise you have been defeated."

def play_again():
    answer = raw_input("Would you like to play again? y/n: ")
    if answer in ("y", "Y", "yes", "Yes", "Of course!"):
        return answer
    else:
        print "Thank you very much for playing our game. See you next time!"

def scores():
    global player_score, computer_score
    print " HIGH SCORES"
    print "Player: ", player_score
    print "Computer: ", computer_score

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Comment: [`print` is a function in Python 3.](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html) You'll have to enclose values that you want to print in parentheses. print("Let's play a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors.")

Answer (score 1):

1) You have an indentation error here :

```
try:
            player = int(player)
            if player in (1,2,3):
                return player
except ValueError: #Try Except Block Statement
            pass
            Print "Oops! I didn't understand that. Please enter 1, 2 or 3."
```

---

2) Also :

```
if rules[player} == computer: #Error in this line
```

Should be :

```
if rules[player] == computer:
```

---

3) Indentation error in if else.

```
if player == computer:
    print "Tie Game."
else:
    if rules[player} == computer:
    print "Your victory has been assured."
    player_score +=1
else: #Incorrect indentation
    print "The computer laughs as you realise you have been defeated."
```

This should be :

```
    if rules[player} == computer:
        print "Your victory has been assured."
        player_score +=1
    else:
        print "The computer laughs as you realise you have been defeated."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if rules[player} == computer:
```

The curly brace should be a bracket.

Answer (score 0):

```
if rules[player} == computer:
print "Your victory has been assured."
player_score +=1
```

First error: rules[player} => rules[player]
second error, you need to ident the lines after the if.

```
else:
    if rules[player} == computer:
        print "Your victory has been assured."
        player_score +=1
    else:
        print "The computer laughs as you realise you have been defeated."
```

Third error: you can't have 2 elses for a single if